# PCA components - do they represent the features or the samples?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, image-processing

Consider the task to apply dimensional reduction to extract "salient" features from images.

I am confused about what components in PCA represents: features or samples ?

I understand that PCA projects samples on an orthogonal directions to maximize variance of their features.

So, I understand that, having an image of shape (64x64), each pixel is a feature.

And when I do:

```
data = image 
data.shape # (64 x 64)

pca_reducer = pca()
pca_reducer.fit(data)
```

I will get:

```
pca_reducer.compontents_.shape
# 64 x 64
```

From there, I could explore which components (which projected rows, I interpret) retains the maximimum variance of the original image.

I am confused in putting in perspective of more than one image:

```
data = np.array([img1.ravel(),  img2.ravel()]) # each image is flattened 
data.shape # (2, 4096)

pca_reducer = pca()
pca_reducer.fit(data)
```

I will get:

```
pca_reducer.components.shape
# 2 x 4096
```

It seems to me that each sample (each image) is treated as a component.

But then, what is the meaning of extracting the components retaining maximum variance ?

Like:

```
pca.transform(data)[:, n_components]
```

It seems to me that would be to extract those images that are used as "directions" or reference for the others.

Instead, I would like to identify the components in terms of features, that is, in terms of regions of pixels of *through*  those images.

Can you help clarify this concept?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the confusion starts here:

"Consider the task to apply dimensional reduction to extract "salient" features from images."

I don't see how PCA could possibly do this.

Comment: I meant using PCA to reduce input vectors for other ML tasks. I refer to example:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html